# os.listdir not reading all files

Tags: python, operating-system, listdir

I am trying to pull a particular line out of each file within a folder.  The code I wrote is opening each file and opening the new output file, although it is looping within each file and outputting data twice in some cases.  I have 15 files within about 800,000 lines between all files.

```
`import os
    for filename in os.listdir("path"):
       fin=open("path\%s" %filename)
       #print fin
       fout=open("newdata.txt","w")
       #print fout
       l=""
       for line in fin:
           p=line.strip().split("\t")
           if p[3]=="Cycle" and p[4]=="Protein":
               l+=line
              fout.write(l)
       #else:pass
  # fin.close()
  # fout.close()`
```

Comment: instead of `w`, use `w+` mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are open file in 'w' mode in the loop, so for each new file it will start output file from scratch, you should open it outside the loop or use 'w+' mode

Comment: Thank you, I opened the new file outside the for loop and now it is reading all my files, although it is still looping and it reads each file within the directory 3-4 times and gives me an output. I only need it to read once, I tried fin.close() and fout.close() and I get an error.